# How to create animation for UIview that needs to pull down to up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I want to create a screen to pull up from down and need to pull down.like iOS notifications screen (but in reverse direction).Please share if any example is there.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can use third party component than [PullableView](https://github.com/crocodella/PullableView) is the right choice for you, just have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

The full-on way to do this in iOS 7 is with an interactive custom transition. You will use a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer and respond to the drag gesture from the edge of the screen by performing part of the transition animation to match the distance the user's finger has travelled. Look into the UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition class to help you do that.

Here's a complete example you can download and run: it happens that I'm doing it from the left or right, not the top or bottom, but it is the same basic idea.

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p296customAnimation2/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.m

But beware: if you try to do it from the top or the bottom you will get interference from the notification center (top) and the control center (bottom). It can be tricky to prevent that interference.

Comment: is it possible in ios6 also?

Comment: No, in iOS 6 you have to directly drag a view, as described in a different answer. But then you will not be able to use a view controller with that view. It will just be a view that you are dragging into the scene. Nothing wrong with that! My answer is simply meant to point out that in iOS 7 there is now a coherent built-in approach to this.

Comment: @Master only because I've switched to Swift. So, now: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p292customAnimation1/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use it.

```
- (void)showShareView {

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.view_Email];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Show"
                    context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3F];

    CGRect frame = self.view_Email.frame;

    if (IS_IPHONE5) {
        if(txtFieldActiveFlag==1){
            frame.origin.y = 568-420;
        }else{
            frame.origin.y = 568-220;
        }
    } else {
        frame.origin.y = 480 - 275 - 88;
    }

    self.view_Email.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)hideShareView {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Show"
                    context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3F];

    CGRect frame = self.view_Email.frame;

    if (IS_IPHONE5) {

        if(txtFieldActiveFlag==2){
            frame.origin.y = 568-220;
        }else{
            frame.origin.y = 568;
        }
    } else {
        frame.origin.y = 480;
    }
    self.view_Email.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


//call method from any button action.

 [self showShareView]; //show the view up

 [self hideShareView]; //show the view down
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Button action i have done.I want using gestures movement.

Comment: ok then you can show the view                                               [self showShareView]; //show the view up
 [self hideShareView]; //show the view down  on gesture recognition.

Comment: Do you need the code of gesture recognization also?

Comment: UIPanGestureRecognizer and UIEdgePanGestureRecognizer are the classes you should try. Give them a whirl and post your code if you get stuck. Tutorials on using gestureRecognizers are widely available with a little google...